# iter('somestring') comes back with nothing for an xml in python 2.7.11

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I am trying to work with the example 20.5.1.4. Finding interesting elements¶
 here :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

```
>>> for neighbor in root.iter('neighbor'):
...     print(neighbor.attrib)
```

Seems pretty straightforward, use it on my xml to search for an element with a name of say 'noiseLevelValues'

I expect to see a list of these (as there are several in XML), it seems iter is not doing its job...The example was pretty straight forward and simple but no idea why iter is not finding anything.

```
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('product.xml').getroot()
        for child in root.iter('noiseLevelValues'):         
            print child.text
```

There are a ton of tags with that lower in the xml tree, but nothing is ever found.   Is there a step I am missing?  I thought iter went through the whole tree from that node?

A snippet with right closing and starting tags here...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<product xmlns="http://www.rsi.ca/rs2/prod/xml/schemas" copyright="RADARSAT-2 Data and Products (c) MacDonald, Dettwiler and Associates Ltd., 2015 - All Rights Reserved." xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.rsi.ca/rs2/prod/xml/schemas schemas/rs2prod_product.xsd">
    <productId>fsafsa</productId>
    <documentIdentifier>adfsdf32</documentIdentifier>
    <sourceAttributes>
        <satellite>asgh426</satellite>
        <sensor>asfd</sensor>
        <inputDatasetId>/aba/31231-2/fasf</inputDatasetId>
        <imageId>378575</imageId>
        <inputDatasetFacilityId>Not Specified</inputDatasetFacilityId>
        <beamModeId>8622</beamModeId>
        <beamModeMnemonic>FQ12W</beamModeMnemonic>
        <rawDataStartTime>2015-02-15T11:01:19.177856Z</rawDataStartTime>
        <radarParameters>
            <acquisitionType>Fine Quad Polarization</acquisitionType>
            <beams>Q12</beams>
        </radarParemters>
    </sourceAttributes>
</product>
```

Comment: The document is in a namespace. This is a common stumbling block. Here is a similar question with an answer that should help, I hope:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/20435500/407651.

Comment: yes that was one hell of a gotcha, thanks for the help!