# How to access specific tag inside xml with elemntree?

Tags: python, xml, tags

I'm trying to parse XML of tasks that includes dependencies and parameters tags, i want to iterate over the task and get the task name, params, depends.
How would you recommend doing it?

I tried to get task by task and get all the data needed by accessing the specific tag.

code i tried:
for elem in root: for subelem in elem.findall('taskFlow'): print(subelem.get['name'])

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:proactive:jobdescriptor:3.2" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:proactive:jobdescriptor:3.2 http://www.activeeon.com/public_content/schemas/proactive/jobdescriptor/3.2/schedulerjob.xsd" name="Extra_02_StartFramegrabbers" projectName="Extra_02_StartFramegrabbers">
  <description>Extra_02_StartFramegrabbers</description>
  <taskFlow>
    <task name="PrepGrabbersEnv">
      <javaExecutable class="exe">
        <parameters>
          <parameter name="command" value="C:\ReplayCode\Apps\PrepareEnvironment\PrepareEnvironment.exe"/>
          <parameter name="arguments" value="C:\ReplayCode\INIFiles\Static\PrepGrabbersEnv.INI"/>
          <parameter name="computers" value="AllComputers"/>
        </parameters>
      </javaExecutable>
      <controlFlow block="none"/>
    </task>
    <task name="FrameGrabber">
      <depends>
        <task ref="NothingAfterKill"/>
      </depends>
      <javaExecutable class="exe">
        <parameters>
          <parameter name="command" value="C:\ReplayCode\Apps\FrameGrabber\FrameGrabber.exe"/>
          <parameter name="arguments" value="C:\ReplayCode\INIFiles\Static\FrameGrabber.ini"/>
          <parameter name="computers" value="FramegrabberComputers"/>
          <parameter name="background" value="true"/>
        </parameters>
      </javaExecutable>
    </task>
    <task name="AutoIniFrameGrabber">
      <javaExecutable class="exe">
        <parameters>
          <parameter name="command" value="C:\ReplayCode\Apps\AutoINI\AutoIni.exe"/>
          <parameter name="arguments" value="C:\ReplayCode\INIFiles\AUTOINI\FrameGrabbers.aip"/>
          <parameter name="computers" value="ControlComputer"/>
        </parameters>
      </javaExecutable>
    </task>
  </taskFlow>
</job>
```

Comment: for elem in root:
    for subelem in elem.findall('taskFlow'):
        print(subelem.get['name'])

Comment: Please see https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/20435500/407651

Comment: saw it already, i think there is somthing in my XML structure that don't understand and prevent me from using those functions the right way.

Comment: Start by uploading a well formed xml so we will be able to help.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and add the codeyou have to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:proactive:jobdescriptor:3.2" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:proactive:jobdescriptor:3.2 http://www.activeeon.com/public_content/schemas/proactive/jobdescriptor/3.2/schedulerjob.xsd" name="Extra_02_StartFramegrabbers" projectName="Extra_02_StartFramegrabbers">
  <description>Extra_02_StartFramegrabbers</description>
  <taskFlow>
    <task name="PrepGrabbersEnv">
      <javaExecutable class="exe">
        <parameters>
          <parameter name="command" value="C:\ReplayCode\Apps\PrepareEnvironment\PrepareEnvironment.exe"/>
          <parameter name="arguments" value="C:\ReplayCode\INIFiles\Static\PrepGrabbersEnv.INI"/>
          <parameter name="computers" value="AllComputers"/>
        </parameters>
      </javaExecutable>
      <controlFlow block="none"/>
    </task>
    <task name="FrameGrabber">
      <depends>
        <task ref="NothingAfterKill"/>
      </depends>
      <javaExecutable class="exe">
        <parameters>
          <parameter name="command" value="C:\ReplayCode\Apps\FrameGrabber\FrameGrabber.exe"/>
          <parameter name="arguments" value="C:\ReplayCode\INIFiles\Static\FrameGrabber.ini"/>
          <parameter name="computers" value="FramegrabberComputers"/>
          <parameter name="background" value="true"/>
        </parameters>
      </javaExecutable>
    </task>
    <task name="AutoIniFrameGrabber">
      <javaExecutable class="exe">
        <parameters>
          <parameter name="command" value="C:\ReplayCode\Apps\AutoINI\AutoIni.exe"/>
          <parameter name="arguments" value="C:\ReplayCode\INIFiles\AUTOINI\FrameGrabbers.aip"/>
          <parameter name="computers" value="ControlComputer"/>
        </parameters>
      </javaExecutable>
    </task>
  </taskFlow>
</job>'''
# ignore namespace
xml = re.sub(' xmlns="[^"]+"', '', xml, count=1)

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
tasks = root.findall('.//taskFlow/task')
for task in tasks:
    print('Task Name: {}'.format(task.attrib['name']))
```

output

```
Task Name: PrepGrabbersEnv
Task Name: FrameGrabber
Task Name: AutoIniFrameGrabber
```