# Python XML ElementTree cannot iter(), find() or findall()

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I can an xml file and loop through the root printing, but `root.iter('tag')`, `root.find('tag')` and `root.findall('tag')` will not work.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<cpe-list xmlns:config="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/configuration/0.1" xmlns="http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:scap-core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.3" xmlns:cpe-23="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-extension/2.3" xmlns:ns6="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns:meta="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-dictionary-metadata/0.2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-extension/2.3 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.3/cpe-dictionary-extension_2.3.xsd http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.3/cpe-dictionary_2.3.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-dictionary-metadata/0.2 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.1/cpe-dictionary-metadata_0.2.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.3 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/nvd/scap-core_0.3.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/configuration/0.1 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/nvd/configuration_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/nvd/scap-core_0.1.xsd">
  <generator>
    <product_name>National Vulnerability Database (NVD)</product_name>
    <product_version>4.4</product_version>
    <schema_version>2.3</schema_version>
    <timestamp>2021-05-21T03:50:31.204Z</timestamp>
  </generator>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:%240.99_kindle_books_project:%240.99_kindle_books:6::~~~android~~">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">$0.99 Kindle Books project $0.99 Kindle Books (aka com.kindle.books.for99) for android 6.0</title>
    <references>
      <reference href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kindle.books.for99">Product information</reference>
      <reference href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t5GXwjw82SyunALVJb2w0zi3FoLRIkfGPc7AMjRF0r4/edit?pli=1#gid=1053404143">Government Advisory</reference>
    </references>
    <cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:a:\$0.99_kindle_books_project:\$0.99_kindle_books:6:*:*:*:*:android:*:*"/>
  </cpe-item>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:%40thi.ng%2fegf_project:%40thi.ng%2fegf:-::~~~node.js~~">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">@thi.ng/egf Project @thi.ng/egf for Node.js</title>
    <references>
      <reference href="https://github.com/thi-ng/umbrella/security/advisories/GHSA-rj44-gpjc-29r7">Advisory</reference>
      <reference href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thi.ng/egf">Version</reference>
    </references>
    <cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:a:\@thi.ng\/egf_project:\@thi.ng\/egf:-:*:*:*:*:node.js:*:*"/>
  </cpe-item>
</cpe-list>
```

The followig Python (3.7) code works:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
infile = open(filename, "r")
xml = infile.read()
infile.close()
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
root = ET.fromstring(xml, parser=parser)
print(root.tag)
for child in root:
    print(child.tag)

Output:
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}cpe-list
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}cpe-item
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}cpe-item
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}cpe-item
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}cpe-item
...
```

But when I try:

`for item in root.iter('cpe-item')` or `for item in root.iter('cpe-list')`, nothing loops.  When I try `for item in root.findall('cpe-item')` or for item in `root.findall('cpe-list')`, nothing loops.  If I try `item = root.find('cpe-list')`, `item = None`.

I don't work with XML very often, but this seems so strage to me since I have some example code of other projects where this works perfectly fine.  Many other examples online show this exact process is the correct process.

What is am I doing wrong?
It seems odd to me that when I `print(root.tag)` or `print(child.tag)` there is something before the tag prints.  I don't know why that is happening.

Comment: You need to take XML namespaces into account. Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/20435500/407651 (and many other questions). See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Answer (score 1):

You are getting entangled with namespaces. A lot has been written about it [and starting here may be a good place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796231/how-does-xpath-deal-with-xml-namespaces).

As for you specific example, the tl;dr is to disregard them altogether. For example:

```
for item in root.findall('.//{*}cpe-item'):
    print(item.tag)
```

Another option is to bite the bullet and declare the namespaces:

```
ns = {"xx":"http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0"}
for item in root.findall('.//xx:cpe-item', ns):
        print(item.tag)
```

output is

```
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}cpe-item
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}cpe-item
```

Comment: I tried this in my code and it still did not output anything.  Did you test this solution with the xml in the post?

Comment: @jonnyjandles Yes; just copied and pasted.

Comment: Strangely, not working for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNrGb0m_BBU

Comment: OK, I tried with another Linux box and it worked like you said. So I'll try to reinstall xml.

Comment: @jonnyjandles You can't reinstall xml. It may be a problem w/ ElementTree. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @jonnyjandles See edit for another option.

Comment: OP uses Python 3.7. Namespace wildcard search was added in Python 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#xml

Comment: Yes, you are correct that I'm using `Python 3.7 on the MacOS (doesn't work)` and `Python 3.9 on Kali/Debian Linux (does work)`.  Thanks for the info that 3.x version will  cause difference in this situation.

Comment: Also, yes, noted that I tried to re-install xml and could not.  However, I was able to get it working on the MacOs Python 3.7 by installing `lxml` which seems to work with the Xpath / namespacing (not sure exactly which term to use).

Comment: @jonnyjandles  Yes, I personally prefer lxml to ElementTree but lxml wasn't tagged in your question...