# How to extract data from multiple xml tags to csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Page xmlns="http://gigabyte.com/documoto/Statuslist/1.6" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" hashKey="MDAwNTgxMzQtQS0xLjEuc3Zn" pageFile="status-1.1.svg" tenantKey="Staus">
  <Stage description="SPREADER,GB/DD" locale="en" name="SPREADER,GB/DD"/>
  <File Price="0.0" Id="1" item="1" stage_status="true" ForPage="true" Number="05051401">
    <Stage description="" locale="n" name="DANGER"/>
  </File>
  <File Price="0.0" Id="2" item="2" stage_status="true" ForPage="true" Number="05051402">
    <Stage description="" locale="n" name="SPINNERS"/>
  </File>
  <File Price="0.0" Id="3" item="3" stage_status="true" ForPage="true" Number="05051404">
    <Stage description="" locale="n" name="CAUTION"/>
  </File>
</Page>
```

Expected Output in table format is:

price,Id,item,stage_status,Number

0.0,1,1,True,05051401

0.0,1,1,True,05051402

0.0,1,1,True,05051404

I tried this code:

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("status-1.1.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

with open('Data.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=('Price', 'Id', 'item', 'stage_status', 'Number'))
    w.writerheader()
    w.writerows(e.attrib for e in root.findall('.//File'))
```

Comment: The XML has default namespace that you need to take into account. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree#parsing-xml-with-namespaces. Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20447459/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117710/407651

Comment: You did not mention any problem.. Is there a problem?

Comment: @balderman, In the xml I need to extract only three attributes 'item', 'stage_status', 'Number'.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way would be to use pandas. Consider this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_xml('status-1.1.xml')

df2 = df[["Price","Id","item","stage_status","Number"]]
df2 = df2[df2["Price"].isna() == False]
df2.to_csv('Data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work (no external lib is required)

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("status-1.1.xml")
data = []
attr_list = ['Price', 'Id', 'item', 'stage_status', 'Number']
for f in root.findall('.//{http://gigabyte.com/documoto/Statuslist/1.6}File'):
  data.append({a:f.attrib[a] for a in attr_list})
with open('Data.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=attr_list)
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(data)
```

output file

```
Price,Id,item,stage_status,Number
0.0,1,1,true,05051401
0.0,2,2,true,05051402
0.0,3,3,true,05051404
```