# Python: How to get value from specific element from xml file

Tags: python, xml, tags, lxml, elementtree

I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.0668.011.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02 pain.0668.011.02.xsd"> 
    <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>cca82067341ea996fc89c17afb5</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2021-07-10T23:03:11Z</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>64</NbOfTxs>
            <CtrlSum>1334.82</CtrlSum>
            <InitgPty>
                <Nm>Example Company</Nm>
            </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>
        <PmtInf>
            <PmtInfId>cca82067341ea996fc89c17afb5</PmtInfId>
            <PmtMtd>EN</PmtMtd>
            <NbOfTxs>64</NbOfTxs>
            <CtrlSum>1334.82</CtrlSum>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Cd>NORM</Cd>
                </SvcLvl>
                <LclInstrm>
                    <Cd>MAIN</Cd>
                </LclInstrm>
                <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
            </PmtTpInf>
        </PmtInf>
    </CstmrDrctDbtInitn> 
</Document>
```

I want to get all values from Element CtrlSum and write them into a dataframe.

My problem is the `<Document xmlns...>` Tag, which currently prevents me from accessing other values.

I have tried to access the all elements with

```
tree = et.parse('xml_beispiel.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root.findall(".")
```

or

```
root.findall(".//GrpHdr")
```

but only get empty values or the values from `<Document xmlns...>`

Comment: `xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.0668.011.02"` declares a default namespace. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20435500/407651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deal with your namespaces; try this:

```
ns = {'': 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.0668.011.02'}
root.find('.//GrpHdr/CtrlSum',namespaces=ns).text
```

and see if it works.

Comment: I get the following result:

[<Element '{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02}CtrlSum' at 0x000001F2F48B35E0>,
 <Element '{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02}CtrlSum' at 0x000001F2F48B3310>]

How can i access the value from CtrlSum?

Comment: @Pattinger I don't know why you're getting the error; works fine for me. See https://www.online-python.com/RHbLF8MqUX.