# XML XPath Expressions not getting all data from Children

Tags: python, xml, tree, element, elementtree

I have some XML that I am needing to turn into structured data in Python.  When I go to get the data from the XML document below I am not seeing any children printed out.  My problem is that I need to get each row for pumpOp returned while I am only getting 1 record returned with the code below.

There should be 3 records in the bottom of the XML file that get returned.  I need to know how to access each element of the XML below.

I believe this record is a sub-child but when I try to print the children nothing prints.  Code examples are appreciated.

Code I have tried (`for reports in myroot.findall('.//{*}pumpOp'`):   #<-- for some reason this only works with a wild card statement like here or with the full path: `for reports in myroot.findall('.//{http://www.witsml.org/schemas/131}pumpOp'))`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse('C:\\Users\\uname\\Documents\\RPA\\PGE_DOS_K_10H_WITSML\\OpsReport_7_28_2022.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()
print(myroot)

for child in myroot:                    # No Children are printed, why?
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)

reportsArray = []

# iterate over all the nodes
for reports in myroot.findall('.//{*}pumpOp'):   #<-- for some reason this only works with a wild card statement like here or with the full path: for reports in myroot.findall('.//{http://www.witsml.org/schemas/131}pumpOp')
    # access all elements in node
    for element in reports:
        ele_name = element.tag
        ele_value = reports.find(element.tag).text
        print(ele_name, ' : ', ele_value)
```

XML Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<opsReports xmlns="http://www.witsml.org/schemas/131" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.witsml.org/schemas/131  ../obj_opsReport.xsd" version="1.3.1.1">
  <documentInfo>
    <DocumentName>opsReport</DocumentName>
    <FileCreationInformation>
      <FileCreationDate>2022-08-31T16:56:36Z</FileCreationDate>
      <SoftwareName>MUDPRO+</SoftwareName>
      <FileCreator>DDye</FileCreator>
    </FileCreationInformation>
  </documentInfo>
  <opsReport uidWell="PGE_DOS_K_10H" uidWellbore="3_-_Prod._Vertical" uid="1">
    <nameWell>PGE DOS K 10H</nameWell>
    <nameWellbore>3_-_Prod._Vertical</nameWellbore>
    <name>1</name>
    <rig>Nabors 890</rig>
    <dTim>2022-07-29T01:00:00Z</dTim>
    <eTimSpud uom="d">72</eTimSpud>
    <mdReport uom="ft">2672.00</mdReport>
    <tvdReport uom="ft">2672.00</tvdReport>
    <distDrill uom="ft">2672.00</distDrill>
    <engineer>Mike Francis</engineer>
    <activity uid="act-1">
      <phase>3 - Prod. Vertical</phase>
      <operator>CHK</operator>
    </activity>
    <drillingParams uid="dp-1">
      <eTimOpBit uom="h">0</eTimOpBit>
      <mdHoleStop uom="ft">2672.00</mdHoleStop>
      <wtMud uom="lbm/galUS">12.10</wtMud>
    </drillingParams>
    <wbGeometry>
      <dTimReport>2022-07-29T01:00:00Z</dTimReport>
      <mdBottom uom="ft">2672.00</mdBottom>
      <wbGeometrySection uid="wbsection-1">
        <typeHoleCasing>casing</typeHoleCasing>
        <mdTop uom="ft">0.00</mdTop>
        <mdBottom uom="ft">2672.00</mdBottom>
        <idSection uom="in">8.921</idSection>
        <odSection uom="in">9.625</odSection>
      </wbGeometrySection>
      <wbGeometrySection uid="wbsection-12">
        <typeHoleCasing>open hole</typeHoleCasing>
        <idSection uom="in">8.750</idSection>
      </wbGeometrySection>
    </wbGeometry>
    <dayCost uid="dc-1">
      <costClass>mud</costClass>
      <costCode>mud product</costCode>
      <costItemDescription>daily mud product cost</costItemDescription>
      <costAmount currency="$">0.00</costAmount>
    </dayCost>
    <dayCost uid="dc-2">
      <costClass>mud</costClass>
      <costCode>mud package</costCode>
      <costItemDescription>daily mud package cost</costItemDescription>
      <costAmount currency="$">0.00</costAmount>
    </dayCost>
    <dayCost uid="dc-3">
      <costClass>mud</costClass>
      <costCode>mud service</costCode>
      <costItemDescription>daily mud service cost</costItemDescription>
      <costAmount currency="$">90.00</costAmount>
    </dayCost>
    <dayCost uid="dc-4">
      <costClass>mud</costClass>
      <costCode>mud engineering</costCode>
      <costItemDescription>daily mud engineering cost</costItemDescription>
      <costAmount currency="$">950.00</costAmount>
    </dayCost>
    <dayCost uid="dc-5">
      <costClass>mud</costClass>
      <costCode>mud tax</costCode>
      <costItemDescription>daily mud tax cost</costItemDescription>
      <costAmount currency="$">72.80</costAmount>
    </dayCost>
    <fluid uid="fluid-1">
      <type>Oil based</type>
      <locationSample>Suction</locationSample>
      <dTim>2022-07-28T13:00:00Z</dTim>
      <md uom="ft">2672.00</md>
      <density uom="lbm/galUS">12.10</density>
      <visFunnel uom="s">85.0</visFunnel>
      <tempVis uom="degF">150.0</tempVis>
      <pv uom="cP">37.0</pv>
      <yp uom="lbf/100ft2">9.0</yp>
      <gel10Sec uom="lbf/100ft2">7.0</gel10Sec>
      <gel10Min uom="lbf/100ft2">15.0</gel10Min>
      <gel30Min uom="lbf/100ft2">22.0</gel30Min>
      <tempHthp uom="degF">250.0</tempHthp>
      <filtrateHthp uom="mL">7.80</filtrateHthp>
      <filterCakeHthp uom="in/32">3</filterCakeHthp>
      <solidsPc uom="%">29.00</solidsPc>
      <waterPc uom="%">12.00</waterPc>
      <oilPc uom="%">59.00</oilPc>
      <solidsLowGravPc uom="%">22.61</solidsLowGravPc>
      <solidsCalcPc uom="%">27.84</solidsCalcPc>
      <baritePc uom="%">5.23</baritePc>
      <lcm uom="lbm/bbl">0.00</lcm>
      <chloride uom="mg/L">28000</chloride>
      <calcium uom="mg/L">15828</calcium>
      <rheometer uid="rheometer-1">
        <tempRheom uom="degF">150.0</tempRheom>
        <vis3Rpm>4</vis3Rpm>
        <vis6Rpm>5</vis6Rpm>
        <vis100Rpm>20</vis100Rpm>
        <vis200Rpm>33</vis200Rpm>
        <vis300Rpm>46</vis300Rpm>
        <vis600Rpm>83</vis600Rpm>
      </rheometer>
      <lime uom="lbm/bbl">1.42</lime>
      <electStab uom="V">1115.00</electStab>
      <calciumChloride uom="mg/L">332895</calciumChloride>
      <company>Valence Drilling Fluids</company>
      <engineer>Mike Francis</engineer>
      <asg>2.88</asg>
      <solidsHiGravPc uom="%">5.23</solidsHiGravPc>
      <solCorPc uom="%">27.84</solCorPc>
      <comments>Recommended Tour Treatment: Maintain Mud Weight 11.0 APCO          Viscosity 55-65

Adding lime for alkalinity
Adding CACL2 for WPS
Adding XMP for HPHT control
Adding IN FORCE OW PLUS, S &amp; P for emulsion/wetting
Running Diesel 10 bph &amp; Water 3bph  for O/W Ratio &amp; help control LGS
Dusting up active with barite as needed while running centrifuge, diesel &amp; water
Remarks: Finished rig skid to 10H well. Nipple up BOPE and test. Finish rig up flow line and clean sand traps. R/U @ report time.</comments>
    </fluid>
    <fluid uid="fluid-2">
      <type>Oil based</type>
      <locationSample>Suction</locationSample>
      <dTim>2022-07-29T01:00:00Z</dTim>
      <md uom="ft">2672.00</md>
      <density uom="lbm/galUS">11.10</density>
      <visFunnel uom="s">75.0</visFunnel>
      <tempVis uom="degF">150.0</tempVis>
      <pv uom="cP">28.0</pv>
      <yp uom="lbf/100ft2">10.0</yp>
      <gel10Sec uom="lbf/100ft2">4.0</gel10Sec>
      <gel10Min uom="lbf/100ft2">10.0</gel10Min>
      <gel30Min uom="lbf/100ft2">16.0</gel30Min>
      <tempHthp uom="degF">250.0</tempHthp>
      <filtrateHthp uom="mL">8.60</filtrateHthp>
      <filterCakeHthp uom="in/32">3</filterCakeHthp>
      <solidsPc uom="%">22.00</solidsPc>
      <waterPc uom="%">15.00</waterPc>
      <oilPc uom="%">63.00</oilPc>
      <solidsLowGravPc uom="%">15.73</solidsLowGravPc>
      <solidsCalcPc uom="%">20.87</solidsCalcPc>
      <baritePc uom="%">5.14</baritePc>
      <lcm uom="lbm/bbl">0.00</lcm>
      <chloride uom="mg/L">28000</chloride>
      <calcium uom="mg/L">15828</calcium>
      <rheometer uid="rheometer-1">
        <tempRheom uom="degF">150.0</tempRheom>
        <vis3Rpm>3</vis3Rpm>
        <vis6Rpm>4</vis6Rpm>
        <vis100Rpm>16</vis100Rpm>
        <vis200Rpm>27</vis200Rpm>
        <vis300Rpm>38</vis300Rpm>
        <vis600Rpm>66</vis600Rpm>
      </rheometer>
      <lime uom="lbm/bbl">1.42</lime>
      <electStab uom="V">1010.00</electStab>
      <calciumChloride uom="mg/L">271659</calciumChloride>
      <company>Valence Drilling Fluids</company>
      <engineer>Mike Francis</engineer>
      <asg>2.97</asg>
      <solidsHiGravPc uom="%">5.14</solidsHiGravPc>
      <solCorPc uom="%">20.87</solCorPc>
      <comments>Recommended Tour Treatment: Maintain Mud Weight 11.0 APCO          Viscosity 55-65

Adding lime for alkalinity
Adding CACL2 for WPS
Adding XMP for HPHT control
Adding IN FORCE OW PLUS, S &amp; P for emulsion/wetting
Running Diesel 10 bph &amp; Water 3bph  for O/W Ratio &amp; help control LGS
Dusting up active with barite as needed while running centrifuge, diesel &amp; water
Remarks: Finished rig skid to 10H well. Nipple up BOPE and test. Finish rig up flow line and clean sand traps. R/U @ report time.</comments>
    </fluid>
    <pitVolume uid="pv-1">
      <pit uidRef="Active">1</pit>
      <dTim>2022-08-31T16:56:36Z</dTim>
      <volPit uom="bbl">250.0</volPit>
      <densFluid uom="lbm/galUS">12.00</densFluid>
      <descFluid>OBM</descFluid>
    </pitVolume>
    <pitVolume uid="pv-2">
      <pit uidRef="Trip Tank">2</pit>
      <dTim>2022-08-31T16:56:36Z</dTim>
      <volPit uom="bbl">0</volPit>
      <densFluid uom="lbm/galUS">12.00</densFluid>
      <descFluid>OBM</descFluid>
    </pitVolume>
    <pitVolume uid="pv-3">
      <pit uidRef="Slug Pit">3</pit>
      <dTim>2022-08-31T16:56:36Z</dTim>
      <volPit uom="bbl">0</volPit>
      <densFluid uom="lbm/galUS">12.00</densFluid>
      <descFluid>OBM</descFluid>
    </pitVolume>
    <pitVolume uid="pv-4">
      <pit uidRef="Frac #1">4</pit>
      <dTim>2022-08-31T16:56:36Z</dTim>
      <volPit uom="bbl">294.0</volPit>
      <densFluid uom="lbm/galUS">12.00</densFluid>
      <descFluid>OBM</descFluid>
    </pitVolume>
    <pitVolume uid="pv-5">
      <pit uidRef="Frac #2">5</pit>
      <dTim>2022-08-31T16:56:36Z</dTim>
      <volPit uom="bbl">493.0</volPit>
      <densFluid uom="lbm/galUS">12.00</densFluid>
      <descFluid>OBM</descFluid>
    </pitVolume>
    <pitVolume uid="pv-6">
      <pit uidRef="Frac #3">6</pit>
      <dTim>2022-08-31T16:56:36Z</dTim>
      <volPit uom="bbl">486.0</volPit>
      <densFluid uom="lbm/galUS">12.00</densFluid>
      <descFluid>OBM</descFluid>
    </pitVolume>
    <pitVolume uid="pv-7">
      <pit uidRef="Frac #4">7</pit>
      <dTim>2022-08-31T16:56:36Z</dTim>
      <volPit uom="bbl">478.0</volPit>
      <densFluid uom="lbm/galUS">12.00</densFluid>
      <descFluid>OBM</descFluid>
    </pitVolume>
    <pitVolume uid="pv-8">
      <pit uidRef="Frac #5">8</pit>
      <dTim>2022-08-31T16:56:36Z</dTim>
      <volPit uom="bbl">475.0</volPit>
      <densFluid uom="lbm/galUS">12.00</densFluid>
      <descFluid>OBM</descFluid>
    </pitVolume>
    <mudVolume>
      <volTotMudStart uom="bbl">0.0</volTotMudStart>
      <volMudDumped uom="bbl">349.0</volMudDumped>
      <volMudReceived uom="bbl">2776.0</volMudReceived>
      <volMudReturned uom="bbl">0.0</volMudReturned>
      <mudLosses>
        <volLostShakerSurf uom="bbl">0.0</volLostShakerSurf>
        <volLostMudCleanerSurf uom="bbl">0.0</volLostMudCleanerSurf>
        <volLostPitsSurf uom="bbl">0.0</volLostPitsSurf>
        <volLostTrippingSurf uom="bbl">0.0</volLostTrippingSurf>
        <volLostOtherSurf uom="bbl">349.0</volLostOtherSurf>
        <volTotMudLostSurf uom="bbl">349.0</volTotMudLostSurf>
        <volLostCircHole uom="bbl">0.0</volLostCircHole>
        <volLostCsgHole uom="bbl">0.0</volLostCsgHole>
        <volLostCmtHole uom="bbl">0.0</volLostCmtHole>
        <volLostBhdCsgHole uom="bbl">0.0</volLostBhdCsgHole>
        <volLostAbandonHole uom="bbl">0.0</volLostAbandonHole>
        <volLostOtherHole uom="bbl">0.0</volLostOtherHole>
        <volTotMudLostHole uom="bbl">0.0</volTotMudLostHole>
      </mudLosses>
      <volMudBuilt uom="bbl">599.0</volMudBuilt>
      <volMudString uom="bbl">0.0</volMudString>
      <volMudCasing uom="bbl">0.0</volMudCasing>
      <volMudHole uom="bbl">0.0</volMudHole>
      <volMudRiser uom="bbl">0.0</volMudRiser>
      <volTotMudEnd uom="bbl">250.0</volTotMudEnd>
    </mudVolume>
    <mudInventory uid="mi-1">
      <name>DIESEL, GAL</name>
      <itemVolPerUnit uom="galUS">1</itemVolPerUnit>
      <pricePerUnit currency="$">0.00</pricePerUnit>
      <qtyStart>0</qtyStart>
      <qtyAdjustment>0</qtyAdjustment>
      <qtyReceived>18210</qtyReceived>
      <qtyReturned>0</qtyReturned>
      <qtyUsed>2040</qtyUsed>
      <costItem currency="$">0.00</costItem>
      <qtyOnLocation>16170</qtyOnLocation>
    </mudInventory>
    <mudInventory uid="mi-2">
      <name>BARITE 4.1, 100#</name>
      <itemWtPerUnit uom="lbm">100</itemWtPerUnit>
      <pricePerUnit currency="$">14.50</pricePerUnit>
      <qtyStart>0</qtyStart>
      <qtyAdjustment>0</qtyAdjustment>
      <qtyReceived>78</qtyReceived>
      <qtyReturned>0</qtyReturned>
      <qtyUsed>0</qtyUsed>
      <costItem currency="$">0.00</costItem>
      <qtyOnLocation>78</qtyOnLocation>
    </mudInventory>
    <mudInventory uid="mi-3">
      <name>BARITE 4.1, TON</name>
      <itemWtPerUnit uom="tonUS">1</itemWtPerUnit>
      <pricePerUnit currency="$">235.00</pricePerUnit>
      <qtyStart>0</qtyStart>
      <qtyAdjustment>0</qtyAdjustment>
      <qtyReceived>70</qtyReceived>
      <qtyReturned>0</qtyReturned>
      <qtyUsed>0</qtyUsed>
      <costItem currency="$">0.00</costItem>
      <qtyOnLocation>70</qtyOnLocation>
    </mudInventory>
    <pumpOp uid="po-1">
      <pump uidRef="Pump-1">1</pump>
      <idLiner uom="in">5.000</idLiner>
      <lenStroke uom="in">12.000</lenStroke>
      <rateStroke uom="rpm">0</rateStroke>
      <pressure uom="psi">0</pressure>
      <pcEfficiency uom="%">95.00</pcEfficiency>
    </pumpOp>
    <pumpOp uid="po-2">
      <pump uidRef="Pump-2">2</pump>
      <idLiner uom="in">5.000</idLiner>
      <lenStroke uom="in">12.000</lenStroke>
      <rateStroke uom="rpm">0</rateStroke>
      <pressure uom="psi">0</pressure>
      <pcEfficiency uom="%">95.00</pcEfficiency>
    </pumpOp>
    <pumpOp uid="po-3">
      <pump uidRef="Pump-3">3</pump>
      <idLiner uom="in">5.000</idLiner>
      <lenStroke uom="in">12.000</lenStroke>
      <rateStroke uom="rpm">0</rateStroke>
      <pressure uom="psi">0</pressure>
      <pcEfficiency uom="%">95.00</pcEfficiency>
    </pumpOp>
    <costDayMud currency="$">1112.80</costDayMud>
    <nameFormation>Austin Chalk</nameFormation>
    <diaCsgLast uom="in">9.625</diaCsgLast>
    <mdCsgLast uom="ft">2672.00</mdCsgLast>
    <sum24Hr>Finished rig skid to 10H well. Nipple up BOPE and test. Finish rig up flow line and clean sand traps. R/U @ report time.</sum24Hr>
  </opsReport>
</opsReports>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853417/2834978

Comment: "for some reason this only works with a wild card statement like here or with the full path". The reason is that the XML document uses a default namespace that you need to take into account. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces and https://stackoverflow.com/q/20435500/407651

Comment: Add `print(reports)` immediately after `for reports in myroot.findall('.//{*}pumpOp'):`. What do you get? I get three lines like this one: `<Element '{http://www.witsml.org/schemas/131}pumpOp' at 0x000001C2364E7920>`.

Comment: Ok I figured out the problem.  I wasn't letting the loop go thru to get the additional records.  Thanks.