# How to read xml and get text from an element using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm a little bit confused with getting information from xml

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AirShoppingRS Version="16.2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST AirShoppingRS.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Document/>
    <Success/>
    <ShoppingResponseID>
        <ResponseID>2017-10-04T14:35:25.243504</ResponseID>
    </ShoppingResponseID>
    <OffersGroup>
        <AirlineOffers>
            <TotalOfferQuantity>297</TotalOfferQuantity>
            <Owner>SU</Owner>
            <AirlineOffer>
                <OfferID Owner="SU">OFFER5</OfferID>
                <TotalPrice>
                    <SimpleCurrencyPrice Code="RUB">36229</SimpleCurrencyPrice>
                </TotalPrice>
                <PricedOffer>
                    <OfferPrice OfferItemID="5">
                        <RequestedDate>
                            <PriceDetail>
                                <TotalAmount>
                                    <SimpleCurrencyPrice>36229</SimpleCurrencyPrice>
                                </TotalAmount>
                                <BaseAmount>33000</BaseAmount>
                                <Taxes>
                                    <Total Code="RUB">3229</Total>
                                </Taxes>
                            </PriceDetail>
                        </RequestedDate>
                        <FareDetail>
                            <FareComponent>
                                <SegmentReference>SEG_SVOLED_1</SegmentReference>
                                <FareBasis>
                                    <FareBasisCode>
                                        <Code>DFOR</Code>
                                    </FareBasisCode>
                                </FareBasis>
                            </FareComponent>
                        </FareDetail>
                    </OfferPrice>
                </PricedOffer>
            </AirlineOffer>
        </AirlineOffers>
    </OffersGroup>
</AirShoppingRS>
```

How can I read it, using `lxml` library. I try this one `root = etree.fromstring(xml.content)` and then I tried `airline_offers = root.findall("AirlineOffer")`, but get nothing. Guess, I'm doing something wrong. Where do I make mistake? How can I get an element and then text or attribute from it?

UPDATE: `airline_offers = root.findall(".//AirlineOffer")` returns nothing too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElementTree findall() returning empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112121/elementtree-findall-returning-empty-list)

Comment: @Headmaster , are you trying to read all the text, which tags text do you want to read ?

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan `SimpleCurrencyPrice` tag for example

Comment: @Headmaster, but when I try working over your issue it says lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag AirShoppingRS line 2, line 44, column 15. So is this XML you created ?

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan perhaps, I made mistake, copying `xml` to stackoverflow. Try now

Comment: @Headmaster, seriously crazy. I don't know how but as you mentioned your xml is not showing up any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default namespace (`http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST`) is declared on the root element. Here is one way to make it work:

```
airline_offers = root.findall(".//{http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST}AirlineOffer")
```

It is also possible to use a wildcard:

```
airline_offers = root.findall(".//{*}AirlineOffer")
```

An alternative is to define a prefix:

```
NS = {"edist": "http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST"}
airline_offers = root.findall(".//edist:AirlineOffer", namespaces=NS)
```