# How to i extract the data from xml with lxml?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I have problem with extracting data from a xml file what contains the lxml. I've tried to extract data with use of lxml library but i have no output at all.

```
from lxml import etree 
tree = etree.parse("ifm-00028A-20170711-IODD1.1.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
levels = root.findall('DeviceIdentity', root.nsmap)
for DeviceIdentity in levels:
data_1 = int(DeviceIdentity.find('deviceId').text)
print(data_1)
```

[IODD][1]

I need for example get the value from the vendorId and deviceId

Thanks for help !

Sample of the xml file 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih4Tk.png

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please avoid pasting code/text as images. It makes it impossible for others to search.

Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bugs here.

First, [`findall` findall only searches the immediate descendants of an element if it is given a tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112121/elementtree-findall-returning-empty-list). You can use [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) expressions to search deeper. So your `findall` should be

```
levels = root.findall('.//DeviceIdentity', root.nsmap)
```

Then, `deviceId` is an [attribute](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_attributes.htm). You should be able to find it in the element's [attrib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) dictionary. Assuming the rest of your code is correct, it would look something like this:

```
for DeviceIdentity in levels:
    data_1 = int(DeviceIdentity.attrib['deviceId'])
    print(data_1)
```

(In future questions, it would have been helpful to include the sample XML as text, and to be more specific than "no output at all")

Comment: so if the deviceId is the attribute then what is the value of the deviceId?  '650'                      how can i get just this value ?

Comment: @Pawel12345 `DeviceIdentity.attrib['deviceId']`, as shown.

Comment: @Pawel12345 If this answer was useful, please consider upvoting or accepting it using the arrow and check mark to the left of the answer.